# Poisson distribution in the number of accidents

Tags: probability

The average number of accidents in a factory follows the Poisson distribution with an average number of accidents of 0.5 per month. The company pays a bonus of 1000 euros in a fund for employees non-zero accident rate, 500 euros if in a month only 1 or 2 accidents occur and no bonus if more than 2 accidents occur per month.
a) What is the expected amount that the company will give each month?
b) What is the probability that in a period of 3 months he will give a total of exactly 2000 euros in bonus?

In (a) I found P(X=0)=0.607, P(X=1)+P(X=2)=0.379, P(X>2)=0.014, using 0.5 as the Poisson parameter. Thus the amount is 1000*0.607+500*0.379+0*0.014=796,5 euros
Is my way of thinking correct?

But I am really stucked in b question. I think that the new Poisson parameter is 3*0,5=1,5, but I find difficilty in connecting the amount of 2000 euros with the corresponding number of accidents happen. I would really appreciate for your guidance.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hint: There are only a few ways in which the total bonus for three months can be exactly $2000$ euros: (1) two months of $1000$ and a third month of $0$, or (2) one month of $1000$ and two months of $500$.

Comment: Thank you very much! And in order to calculate the possibility, how to connect this information with the corresponding number of accidents? Thank you very much.